# Access non database item of an android list view

Tags: android, listview

I have list view that has two database elements displayed along with a checkbox element which will not be associated with database column.  I want to use checkbox to allow the user to select rows from the listview to be processed.

I have created the following layout for the listView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

     <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/dbCol1View"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip" 

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dbCol2View"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/dbCol1View"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"

        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I then have a database object as follows:

```
public class DbObj{
private int id;
private String dbCol1;
private String dbCol2;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getDbCol1() {
    return dbCol1;
}
public void setDbCol1(String dbCol1) {
    this.dbCol1 = dbCol1;
}
public String getDbCol2() {
    return dbCol2;
}
public void setDbCol2(String dbCol2) {
    this.dbCol2 = dbCol2;
}
```

}

I then use a SimpleCursorAdapter in my code as follows:

```
    String cols[] = { "dbCol1", "dbCol2" };
int views[] = { R.id.dbCol1View, R.id.dbCol2View };
cursor = dbObjDAO.getByCriteria(criteria);

SimpleCursorAdapter ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(rootActivity,
            R.layout.list_layout, cursor, cols, views);

startManagingCursor(cursor);

listView.setAdapter(ca);
```

The list shows up fine and the checkbox is there and can be selected. My question is how can I loop over the listView to find the items who's checkbox has been selected?